# User still online after closing page

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I'm working with a php login script. (and i have a stupid beginner question) The plan is to log off users with a cookie after 1 hour.

But if the user didn't press the logout button the user stayed online (on my database table there keeps a record open on my MySQL db) When I deleted that record everything goes fine and the user can login.

Could somebody help me out?
Do i need to let he script delete my session or something else?

**Solution:** the problem was that i just needed to delete (make sure) that the user login data was deleted before the users wants to login again. So i made a small script that deletes a open session for the user if he want to login. After all i stopped using my own code. Now i am using CodeIgniter and it works good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, that's the way sessions typically work. Once a page is loaded, there's no connection between the browser and the server anymore. Basically, once a page has finished loading and is just sitting there in the browser, it's already the same as if the user had closed the window.

There's no way to 100% reliably detect whether a user is still "online" or not. You'd have to have a Javascript send a constant heartbeat for that, but even with this it comes down to **timeouts**. If you have not seen the user for a certain amount of time, assume he is offline and delete the session. That's all you can do.

Comment: so you mean by a cronjob? or is there a other way to do this?

Comment: There are many different ways, depending on your situation. A completely "passive" way is to never delete anything and just use appropriate queries (`SELECT ... WHERE last_seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`). Secondly, you can do a "poor man's cron job" by running some garbage collection *sometimes* on random requests (e.g. `if (mt_rand(0, 1000) == 1000) run_cleanup()`. PHP's session handling does this. Lastly, you can use real cron jobs. In a real world app you usually have some combination of all three.

Comment: @Roy You don't *have* to delete records, you could just keep them forever (I'm not necessarily advocating the idea, just pointing it out). I don't know why this would prevent your user from logging in, it doesn't have to. If it does it's your specific problem.

Comment: @Roy I don't understand the question. It sounds to me like your login/session system does not work correctly because you are making bad assumptions about how sessions should be deleted and how parallel session should work. You should fix your approach and understand first and foremost.

Comment: hello, i created a new sql delete. when a user sign in, this will fire and delete the session from the user, if it's there.